# Zend Framework 2 formInput or formElement ID tag not rendering

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework2, zend-form2

In Zend framework 2, when I use the view's **formRow** method like so

```
$this->formRow($form->get('product_name'));
```

it will generate HTML like this

```
<label for="product_name">
    <span>Name</span>
    <input type="text" id="product_name" name="product_name">
</label>
```

but if I use **formInput**

```
<div class="control-group">
    <?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('product_name')->setLabelAttributes(array('class'=>'control-label'))); ?>
    <div class="controls">
        <?php echo $this->formInput($form->get('product_name')); ?>
    </div>
</div>

$this->formInput($form->get('product_name'));
```

i don't get the id tag

```
<input type="" name="product_name">
```

I've tried with formElement with same results.

**How can I get it to render just the input with all attributes and values?**

This is how my **Zend Framework 2 View** looks like (simplified)

```
<?php echo $this->form()->openTag($form); ?>    
<div class="control-group">
    <?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('product_name')->setLabelAttributes(array('class'=>'control-label'))); ?>
    <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->formInput($form->get('product_name')); ?></div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit')); ?></div>
</div>

<?php echo $this->form()->closeTag(); ?>
```

and the **Zend Framework 2 Form**

```
<?php
namespace Product\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;

class ProductForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct($name = null)
    {
        // we want to ignore the name passed
        parent::__construct('product');
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
        $this->setAttribute('class','form-horizontal');

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'product_name',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'text',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Name',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'submit',
                'value' => 'Save',
                'id' => 'submitbutton',
                'class'=>'btn btn-success btn-large'
            ),
        ));
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Current Zend 2 does not generate form like this .............

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'product_name',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'text',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Name',
        ),
    ));
```

to:

```
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'product_name',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'text',
            'id'    => 'product_name',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Name',
        ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually this code:

```
 $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
        'name' => 'product_name',
        'attributes' => array(
            'id'    => 'product_name',
            'class' => 'span3',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Your label',            
        ),
    ));
```

could be used correctly by a css renderer like Bootstrap due to fact that the `$this->formRow(...)` form helper will produce:

```
<label for="product_name">Your label</label><input type="text" name="product_name" class="span3" id="product_name" value="">
```

which is more readable than the original `formRow` output (without id neither class attributes)